# Is it okay to refer to high-rise buildings and something like them as topographic features?

Tags: word-usage

I assumed the ground as one flat 2D plane.
Then, a lot of things will be placed over the plane, e.g., traffic lights, high-rise apartments, buildings, telephone poles, any structures, etc.
I assumed any each of such things as a simple cuboid.
Then, I assumed that each cuboid's coordinates, length, width, height are known to me.
Then, I utilized those parameters.

In this case, can I make the title as follows?

> Development of Blah-Blah-Blah Technique Utilizing Topographic Features.

My dictionary outputs the term "Topographic Features."
But I want to ask how the English natives think of this term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Who is your target audience? Is this a game design, an urban planning project, a visual modelling exercise, or something else?

Assuming you mean the science of [city/urban planning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urban_planning), "topography/topographic" is certainly used and understood in that field, and is completely okay.

If you're inventing the topography yourself, rather than measuring the topography of an actually-existing place, perhaps "topographic modelling" is better than "topographic features".

(Note that I use British spelling, hence 'modelling' instead of 'modeling'.)

Comment: Thank you for a valuable comment. Actually, I am writing a journal paper that proposes an algorithm that finds an optimal position of something like a base station considering given information about such data. So, the target audience must be the engineering researchers, students, etc. majoring in wireless communications or so.

Comment: Topographic Data/Modelling should be fine. 'Digital Surface Model' or 'Digital Elevation Model' (e.g. https://up42.com/blog/tech/everything-you-need-to-know-about-digital-elevation-models-dem-digital) should also work. You could also look at past articles in the specific journal you're submitting to to see what's the norm, or ask colleagues in the same field for their opinion.